# Cannot read property of null on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  var select = document.getElementById('party_size');
  select.selectedIndex = select.options.length-1;
});
```

And here is the html, rendered from `.erb`. The amount of option fields is dynamic.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
  There will be
  <select onchange="partySize.call(this, event)" name="reservation[party_size]" id="party_size">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
  people in my party.
</div>
```

On page load, Google Chrome is returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null` and the select is not selecting the last option, which is what the javascript is designed to do.

On refresh, the error does not fire as well as the javascript works correctly (the select field properly selects the last option). In the above example, the option with the value of `3` is selected.

What do I need to change with the javascript to make it properly fire on page load?

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: Just in case, you might want to change "select" to another variable name.

Comment: @kazenorin updated.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `partySize` as well? Because the code above runs as expected as I tested.

Comment: what do you mean by page load? _`On refresh, the error does not fire as well as the javascript works correctly`_ even when you refresh its a page load.